# Butter Knife Build Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Using Android Studio 3.1.1, I'm try to add Butter Knife to project but build gradle fail.

the module level:

```
{   ...
    dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'}
```

And below is the build project level:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCwK4.png)

I recreated the new project from scratch and tested any solutions everybody said, but it does not work and still it does fail with this message:

```
Failed to resolve: support-compat
```

Comment: show your module level build.gradle

Comment: why did you wrote extra 'androidTestImplementation' in your dependecies?

Answer (score 3):

Eraser all your changes and just add:

```
  dependencies {
.
.
.
.
.
.

      implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
      annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Downgrad to

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
```

and `classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.4.0'`

Answer (score 1):

Ad this in your project level gradle

```
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { name 'Sonatype SNAPSHOTs'; url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' }
    }

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT' // here
}
```

And apply plugin on  app level gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'//here
```

Comment: Unable to find method 'com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariant.getOutputs()Ljava/util/List;'

Comment: @Amir use the snapshot version of butter knife. As this issue is already reported https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1130

Answer (score 1):

your problem is you added extra `implementation` keyword in your dependencies, change your project dependencies with code below

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
        annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
```